# How To Implement A Better Build Strategy for Next.js App

Tags: deployment, next.js, create-react-app, pm2

I am hosting a [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) app on [digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/) and managing it as a process using [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io/).

Everything is working well except when I am pushing changes to server. Both [create react app](https://create-react-app.dev/) and [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) are unavailable at build time, [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) return a server error or not found error when building the apps. When using [create react app](https://create-react-app.dev/) I would build the files on my local computer and send them to the server using ssh which allowed for quicker updates. I can't see how the same is possible with [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/).

My main problem is how I can still build the [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) while still making the previous build available until the current build is complete.

Answer (score 1):

make one bash script and insert condition
if name "a" folder is available then create "b"
elif if name "b" folder is available then create "a"
else create name "a" folder

2. if name "A" folder available then create name "b" folder and run all commands on name "b" folder like "npm i " npm run build " after complete of execution . then delete name "a" folder then run pm2 stop appname then go through name "b" folder and run pm2 start
3. thease all commands run through bash script

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).